# Can't overwrite CSS for media query

Tags: css, media-queries

https://codepen.io/everybodysfeelingwonderland/full/OjyRpM/

Somehow I can't change the color of my Nav links for a smaller screen size in my media query. It should turn white, but it just stays gray as for the bigger screens.

```
@media all and (max-width: 580px) {
  nav li a,
  nav ul li {
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 20px;   
}
```

Comment: You should use a mobile first approach. The initial styling should be how you want it to look on mobile and then use a media query to change the styling once it gets to 580px. The media query you are using right now will be overridden because the media query is higher in the CSS than the desktop styling. Also, you're using `//` to comment a line out which is a Javascript comment. CSS is `/* */`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Media queries do not add specificity to a selector. They just control if the code inside is ignored or not.

Which means that...

```
@media (condition) {
  a selector {
    some value
  }
}
a selector {
  another value
}
```

...will always apply *"another value"*, because ***it's placed later and has same specificity***. You need to invert them and they will work as intended:

```
a selector {
  another value
}
@media (condition) {
  a selector {
    some value
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks mate, I didn't know that you have to pay attention how you order your CSS, thought you only need to in JS, thanks man, it's now working

Comment: Order in CSS is very important. You want to keep the specificity as low as possible and arrange conditions so the one that should apply is always read last. That's the ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The media queries should be in the lowest section of the CSS.
If I first define the media queries; and define regular CSS below, the lower matches override the once defined before.

It's quite common to put media queries to the bottom part of the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Your media query rule should be *after/below* the regular rule. In your current code, the media query rule for `nav li a` is at line 104, the general rule is at line 162, i.e. *after* the media query rule - so it's overwriting the previous rule.

Just move your media queries to the bottom (or at leat below the according general rules if you wirte them one by one), this will fix your problem.